# Dotnet publish cannot upload to other project package generic registry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I create the gitlab, like below

```
publish_and_zip:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet publish ${PROJECT} --no-restore -c Release -o publish_output
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y zip
    - cd publish_output
    - zip -r $ARTIFACT_NAME ./
  when: on_success
  needs:
    - build-job
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - publish_output/$ARTIFACT_NAME
    expire_in: 1 week

upload_to_generic_package_repository:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - publish_and_zip
  script:
    - echo "start upload to ${CI_API_V4_URL}/api/v4/projects/$DeployProjectId/packages/generic/ARTIFACT_NAME/$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
    - curl --request POST \
      --header "Private-Token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" \ 
      --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
      --form "file=@publish_output/$ARTIFACT_NAME" \
      "${CI_API_V4_URL}/api/v4/projects/$DeployProjectId/packages/generic/ARTIFACT_NAME/$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
```

But the output at the end, turn out

```
$ curl --request POST \ --header "Private-Token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" \ --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \ --form "file=@publish_output/$ARTIFACT_NAME" \ "${CI_API_V4_URL}/api/v4/projects/$DeployProjectId/packages/generic/ARTIFACT_NAME/$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
```

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: publish_output

But I pretty sure the ${CI_API_V4_URL} can reolve and $DeployProjectId can return numeric
can I know what's wrong inside ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a YAML formatting issue. Use a multiline yaml string to format this correctly including line breaks:

```yaml
    - |
      curl --request POST \
           --header "Private-Token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" \ 
           --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
           --form "file=@publish_output/$ARTIFACT_NAME" \
           "${CI_API_V4_URL}/api/v4/projects/$DeployProjectId/packages/generic/ARTIFACT_NAME/$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
```

Without the multiline string (`- |`) the string gets interpreted as a single line including the backslashes like so:

```
curl --request POST \ --header "Private-Token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" \ --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \ --form "file=@publish_output/$ARTIFACT_NAME" \ "${CI_API_V4_URL}/api/v4/projects/$DeployProjectId/packages/generic/ARTIFACT_NAME/$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
```

Because of the bad formatting for the bash command, this produces the malformed URL error.

But when the command is correctly formatted, there is no error.

---

As a side note, you are also missing a `$` before `ARTIFACT_NAME` in your URL. Though, this is not necessarily the cause of the curl error.

Comment: Thank you, and right now I've got 
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
whatever, I create personal token or use ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} is no working

Comment: Yeah, seems like some things are not quite right, but that's kind of a separate issue. Double check the [examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/#publish-a-generic-package-by-using-cicd) and try using the code they provide there. Keep in mind the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` only gives access to the current project (e.g., `$CI_PROJECT_ID`) unless you've explicitly provided access from the other project's settings. If you still can't figure out the new issues you're having, consider opening a separate question @CarrieKaski